# Find a selected radiobutton via Selenium/Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2 (Webdriver) for automating tests on a webpage.
However I wonder if there is way to find out if a radiobutton is selected or not using webdriver framework?

I can find the element and click it by using Click() method.
I would like to test that it actually was set, or is that implicit done by the Click() method on IWebElement object?

(Using C# and NUnit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine if an element is selected by catching the element and then checking selected.

```
IWebElement thisElement = driver.FindElement(By.ID(//radiobutton id));
if(thisElement.Selected)
{
//do something here.
}
```

you can do this other ways but the `.Selected` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well you are absolutely right. However I did not manage to see the state of the the boolean to toogle in the beginning. I was actually able to set the checkbox on and off by a "faulty" xpath statement. When the xpath string was pointing to a "//input" the state of selected was working! Thanks!

Comment: its `.Selected` or `.isSelected`?

Comment: @Maitreya depends on your version.  Webdirver (C#) which is what the OP was talking about it is .Selected.  However .Selected doesn't exist in the Java API so in that case it would be .isSelected.

Answer (score 2):

```
webDriver.findElement(By.className("radio")).click();

Boolean radio = webDriver.findElement(By.className("radio")).isEnabled();

   if(radio.booleanValue()==true){

      result.addPassedTestStepResult("user cannot uncheck the radiobutton");
   }
```